# Why cant i create a mysql table containing MEDIUMTEXT

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-workbench, create-table

I was trying to store large strings[~10000 chars] using mysql. I read around and found out i need to use MEDIUMTEXT columns to achieve this,
When i attempt to create a table with:

```
 CREATE TABLE `a`.`computers` (
       `PC` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
       `Last_Online` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
       `Question` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
       `Response` MEDIUMTEXT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (`PC`))
        ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4;
```

I get `Error:1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`
I am new to mysql so i would appreciate if you could explain in detail.

Comment: provide complete definition for computers table because you have defined PC_Name as pk but not in your field definition

Comment: sorry, i edited the table names and forgot to change the PK